# iOS Dismiss and Present view controller custom animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, viewcontroller

I have a view controller that I am presenting with the following objective c code:

```
CATransition *animation=[CATransition animation];
animation.delegate=self;
animation.duration=0.3;
animation.type=kCATransitionMoveIn;
animation.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight;

[self presentViewController:reader animated:NO completion:nil];
[reader.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

and dismissing with similar code inside a delegate method

```
CATransition *animation=[CATransition animation];
animation.delegate=self;
animation.duration=0.3;
animation.type=kCATransitionMoveIn;
animation.subtype=kCATransitionFromLeft;

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

However there is one problem: unlike using a navigation controller where you see one view slide onto other view; here the old view just disappears instantly so the new view moves
onto a blank view.

How do I fix this problem? I need this code to work in IOS 6,7 and 8 and would like it to look like the horizontal animation you see when going back and forth between views that are inside navigation controllers.

Edit:
The solution I accepted has a bug with iOS 6, if I can find a solution that fixes it, I'll edit this post.

Edit 2:
Found it. It appears that since I am presenting a zBar view controller I need to use this code

```
zbarController.wantsFullScreenLayout=NO;
```

after I set the cameraOverlayView.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Presenting a view controller using a custom animation:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:reader animated:NO];
```

Dismissing a view controller using a custom animation:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];    
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works great in IOS 7, but there are a few kinks in 6. When I navigate to the new view in portrait mode the status bar is solid black. In addition when I rotate from portrait to landscape the solid bar is covered by the navigation bar which has moved up to the very top. Why might that happen?

Comment: I'm not sure why the status bar would just stop displaying properly. The status bar settings in iOS have changed so many times over the years that the problem could be caused by any number of things, ranging from global settings in your app delegate, to your view controller, or if you're using a drawer navigation control it may be a problem with that. Sorry I can't be of more help on that one.

Comment: That's ok, I'll post up a new question if I can't figure it out for myself eventually. Thanks for your help! I'll mark your answer as accepted and update the original post if I find a solution that fixes the iOS 6 bug.

Comment: So, `0.3` is default duration?