# How to change the default transition while presenting UIViewController to custom

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, transition

i am trying to present another UIViewController from my current view controller. The transition animation is set to default and the presented UIViewController seems to be appearing from bottom to top . however i am trying to set the animation from top to Bottom. How can i acheive this?
I have tried using transition effects as cover vertical, flip horizontal, cross dissolve but none of them seems according to my choice. Any suggestions how can I achieve this?

```
 let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let editCategoryVC: EditCategoryVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("editCategoryVC")as EditCategoryVC
        self.presentViewController(editCategoryVC, animated:true, completion: nil
```

)

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26859432/2082569

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TransitionHandler helper class that handles animation

```
import UIKit

class TransitionHandler : NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate  {

    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {

        return 0.9
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let container = transitionContext.containerView
        let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!
        let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!

        // e.g to show the animation from x axis change this frame as required
        //   let offScreenUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-container.frame.size.width, 0)
        //     let offScreenDown = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container.frame.size.width,0)
        let offScreenUp = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0) // (-container.frame.size.width,0)
        let offScreenDown = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: container.frame.size.height)
        toView.transform = offScreenUp
        container.addSubview(toView)
        container.addSubview(fromView)
        let duration = self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {

            fromView.transform = offScreenDown
            toView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    }, completion: { finished in

            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
    })

    }
}
```

Your class that shows next controller on button click

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let transitionHandler = TransitionHandler()

    @IBAction func showVCAnimation(sender: AnyObject) {

        var storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nextVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("editCategoryVC") as EditCategoryVC
        nextVC.transitioningDelegate =  self.transitionHandler
        self.presentViewController(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Well Thanks to AppCoda!!!

Answer (score -1):

the following can work i think

```
let editCategoryVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("editCategoryVC") as editCategoryVC
self.presentViewController(editCategoryVC, animated:true, completion: nil
```

Comment: thats the problem..the animation with this piece of code goes from bottom to top while presenting the view controllers. I want animation from top to bottom